# Gaussian Process with non-negative basis coefficients

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, constrained-regression

I'm interested in adding basis functions to a Gaussian Process. In particular, following [Section 2](https://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf) of Rasmussen's book, I have
$$g(x)=f(x) + h(x)^\top\beta,\qquad f(x)\sim\mathcal{GP}\left(0,k\left(x,x'\right)\right).$$
In the book, $\beta\sim\mathcal N\left(b,B\right)$ and therefore, everything can be nicely derived by completing squares.

Is there a robust way to estimate this specification with a non-negativity constraint on the parameters? In other words, with $\beta\ge 0$?